# Sencha Touch 2 vs DHTMLX Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, dhtmlx

I'm in a bit of a doubt about this subject.

**Situation:**

I have conducted a research which stated that Sencha Touch 2 (further Sencha) and DHTMLX Touch (further DHTMLX) where the best two frameworks to choose from.

What these frameworks have to do is the following.

I have to dynamically (at server side) instantiate objects which at client side will be translated to Sencha or DHTMLX controls. Also the actions that a specific control will have will be made at client side.

What this means is that I have to "wrap" around the Sencha or DHTMLX controls with my own objects and use these object to interact with the server.

Until so far I have been able to "wrap" DHTMLX controls but I can't figure out how to with Sencha. I don't seem to understand the structure (after two weeks of building tutorials and experimenting)

**Question**

What framework would you chose to use and why?
Take into account that both frameworks offer what is needed and both more then qualify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would (do) use DHTMLX because the documentation is so good. There are tons of examples. The docs are well organized and about as thorough as one could expect for even an enterprise product. Considering it's free, this is nothing short of miraculous.

Comment: And what are your experiences with DHTMLX Touch?